# ¿Que api puedo utilizar para calcular el tiempo de llegada de un punto a otro, pasandole una ruta predeterminada?

Tags: api

Necesito una API de google maps(para android) que diga el tiempo de llegada de un punto a otro, pero no no tomando el camino mas corto sino que lo hago de acuerdo a una ruta preestablecida

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad primeramente, este tipo de preguntas no son validas aquí ya que se basan principalmente en opiniones, puedes agregar código de lo que has intentado ya que tampoco refleja algún tipo de esfuerzo, aun así te dejo una alternativa que espero te ayude.

Comment: Saludos @yazidns17 bienvenid@ a SOes, te invito a dar una vuelta por http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para que entres en sintonía con el sitio, de la misma manera te invito a darle una lectura a un post desde mi teclado: http://fredyfx.com/saludos-nueva-generacion-de-programadores espero que lo tomes a bien :D

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar esta, es un GET:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Respuesta en JSON:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "origin_addresses": [ "Vancouver, BC, Canada", "Seattle, État de Washington, États-Unis" ],
  "destination_addresses": [ "San Francisco, Californie, États-Unis", "Victoria, BC, Canada" ],
  "rows": [ {
    "elements": [ {
      "status": "OK",
      "duration": {
        "value": 340110,
        "text": "3 jours 22 heures"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 1734542,
        "text": "1 735 km"
      }
    }, {
      "status": "OK",
      "duration": {
        "value": 24487,
        "text": "6 heures 48 minutes"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 129324,
        "text": "129 km"
      }
    } ]
  }, {
    "elements": [ {
      "status": "OK",
      "duration": {
        "value": 288834,
        "text": "3 jours 8 heures"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 1489604,
        "text": "1 490 km"
      }
    }, {
      "status": "OK",
      "duration": {
        "value": 14388,
        "text": "4 heures 0 minutes"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 135822,
        "text": "136 km"
      }
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

Si te fijas te da la distancia y el tiempo.

Checa la documentación [aquí](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro).